# how do I access this selector and add a listener

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, onclick

here is my html
`<span class="btn btn-small"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>`

here is what I tried but my breakpoint never stops inside this method when my selector is clicked

```
$('span.btn-small').click(function () {
//run ajax call
// actions
var i;
i = 0;
});
```

I thought this would apply to that selector because it is a span tag with a btn-small class

Comment: Yes it should, but where are you running this code? Is it inside of `$(document).ready()` or **after** the element in the HTML? Otherwise, it won't bind an event to any elements because they won't be ready and won't be found by the selector

Comment: It should work. Check this - http://jsfiddle.net/JSWorld/pyASp/

Comment: @JSWorld That's only because the fiddle's JavaScript is set to run `onLoad`. Otherwise, it would only work if the JavaScript was executed after the span

Comment: @Ian it was outside of the document.ready() , I had a hunch that might have been it but I wasn't sure, thank you. You could post that as an answer because it is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector should work. It selects all `<span>` elements with the class `btn-small`.

It all depends on where that code is being executed. The element needs to be ready/rendered, so that it can be found and an event can be bound to it. That is accomplished by 1 of the following:

- `$(document).ready(func)` (or `$(window).on("load", func)`, or similar)
- Binding the event **after** the span in the HTML (like at the end of the `<body>`). This is probably the easiest to do and doesn't block the HTML from being parsed/rendered.
- Event delegation (probably unnecessary for your situation, because it's more for dynamic elements)

Comment: I like how this answer covers multiple alternative approaches to the problem :) It's worth adding that putting the script after the element in the html is probably the easiest.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks :) Good point, I'd be glad to add it in! Feel free to add/edit and reword anything. Sometimes I have a hard time wording things, even if it's an easy subject